# CSS Modules: Best practice combining classnames?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, css-modules

I'm using css-modules in a ReactJS app I'm developing.

```
<div>
  <div className={styles.homeLink}>home</div>
  <div className={styles.aboutLink}>about</div>
</div>
```

if I need to have a class for all menu divs (home, about) and also specific class for each of the links that style them then I need to create a shared class for all the links. I think there are different ways to do it:

```
/* First code using composes */
.links {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:left;
}
.homeLink {
  composes: links;
  color: #FFF;
}
.aboutLinks {
  composes: links;
  color: #CCC;
}
```

I uses composes from a class in the same file here. In this case I need to use only one class name in my JSX.

2 other ways:

```
/* Second code using combined classes and multiple classes later */
.links {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:left;
}
.links.homeLink {
  color: #FFF;
}
.links.aboutLinks {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

or maybe:

```
/* Third code using multiple classes later */
.links {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:left;
}
.homeLink {
  color: #FFF;
}
.aboutLinks {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

In second and third code I need to have 2 classes in each className prop:

```
<div>
  <div className={className(styles.links, styles.homeLink)}>home</div>
  <div className={className(styles.links, styles.aboutLink)}>about</div>
</div>
```

I've seen people do this in different ways. Which one is easier, have better performance and scale better in larger apps?

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based or requires discussion** and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have provided full details and this isn't opinion based. I'm asking for best practices, there are hundreds of questions like this. You really down voted for being too broad?

Comment: If you are asking for which is **better** it clearly IS opinion based, "Best" is subjectiive and so, again, **opinion based**.

Comment: @Paulie_D But better option is based on facts not opinion. There's only one way to do this right, but do what you like.

Comment: No, there's *many* ways to do it right...*"Which one is easier"* is asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for 2nd or 3rd option since it avoids CSS code duplication.

Which one of these two, it depends on broader context.

If `.homeLink` would be helpful somewhere else on the site (to style some other *homelink* in a similar way), then 3rd. Otherwise, 2nd solution to keep CSS rules as strict as possible.

Comment: Since the questioner is using CSS Modules, the first option does not duplicate CSS. `styles.homeLink` will apply both the `links` class being composed and the `homeLink` class to the element (or their equivalent compiled local class names). The first option is more in keeping with CSS Modules' intended usage and avoids replicating CSS module functionality with shipped JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

your options is depends on difference  scenario, based on your code 
it is 2nd option is better if it contains other div tag and same classes than third option css apply to that so 2nd option is better